# How to use after() if a function with sleep is called in the GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have got an external class with a function in which I wait 30 seconds and afterwards increment the temperature.

```py
def incTemperature(incedTempVal, endTemperature):
    tempCurrentTemperature = read_current_Temperature()
    while(True):
        if(round(tempCurrentTemperature,1) < float(endTemperature)):
            tempCurrentTemperature = read_current_Temperature()
            temp = read_fixed_Temperature_of_specific_f(1)

            if(round(tempCurrentTemperature,1) >= float(endTemperature)):
                break

            if(round(tempCurrentTemperature,1) == temp):

                temp = round(temp + float(incedTempVal),1)
                setTemperature(temp)
                print('Erhoehe um 0.1 Grad bis' + endTemperature + ' Grad')
                time.sleep(30)
        else: break
```

This function is called in my GUI class:

```py
  def startEvent():
            sp.startHeat()
            sp.setTemperature(self.EntryStartEins.get())
            sp.incTemperature(self.EntryTemperatureInc.get(), self.EntryEndTemperature.get())
```

How can I work with after() in the GUI when my function call in which I let my program sleep for 30 seconds? I guess I have to recode my function to let it work as I want to right? But how can I realise it if I need this timeout in the function?

**Update#2, thanks for Mike's advice:**

I extended my code with return values

```py
if(round(tempCurrentTemperature,1) == temp):

            temp = round(temp + float(incedTempVal),1)
            setTemperature(temp)
            print('Erhoehe um 0.1 Grad bis' + endTemperature + ' Grad')
            return 1
        else: return 3
```

so that I can execute after() with 0 delay or with 30 seconds.

```py
            if(returnValueForLoop == 3):
                returnValueForLoop = root.after(0, sp.incTemperature, self.EntryTemperatureInc.get(), self.EntryEndTemperature.get())
            elif(returnValueForLoop == 0):
                print("Stop!")
                return                    

            if(returnValueForLoop == 1):
                returnValueForLoop = root.after(30000, sp.incTemperature, self.EntryTemperatureInc.get(), self.EntryEndTemperature.get())
            elif(returnValueForLoop == 0):
                print("Stop!")
                return
```

But it just executes once. So this does not work.

Comment: Do you mean to call after() on a widget? The function works like so: widget.after(miliseconds, function_to_call). You would have to implement it with incTemperature as the function.

Comment: You don't... Do not use `sleep()` in tkinter. Instead rework your functions to use `after()` only.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how yoour method doesn't have `self` argument, but still, your method should call itself every 30 seconds. If your tk.Tk window instance is `root`:

```
def incTemperature(incedTempVal, endTemperature, root):
    tempCurrentTemperature = read_current_Temperature()
    if(round(tempCurrentTemperature,1) < float(endTemperature)):
        tempCurrentTemperature = read_current_Temperature()
        temp = read_fixed_Temperature_of_specific_f(1)

        if(round(tempCurrentTemperature,1) >= float(endTemperature)):
            break

        if(round(tempCurrentTemperature,1) == temp):

            temp = round(temp + float(incedTempVal),1)
            setTemperature(temp)
            print('Erhoehe um 0.1 Grad bis' + endTemperature + ' Grad')

    root.after(30000, incTemperature, self.EntryTemperatureInc.get(), self.EntryEndTemperature.get(), root)
```

Changed start function where you pass the `root` instance:

```
def startEvent():
    sp.startHeat()
    sp.setTemperature(self.EntryStartEins.get())
    sp.incTemperature(self.EntryTemperatureInc.get(), self.EntryEndTemperature.get(), root)
```

Comment: This won't work I guess, because root.after is not known in this class.
It is an external class / function. The Tkinter class in which I call my function is not the same class.

Comment: It doesn't matter, replace `root` with any variable you want or pass root instance to function (and repeat it in after call).

Comment: Okay now it does not freeze anymore, but the main problem now is that every call lasts 30 seconds  It has to be 30 seconds when my last statement is true otherwise my program run in milliseconds to check if the statement got true or not.

Comment: @ebug38 Then write the conditional statement that decides how long `after()` is called for.

Comment: @ipaleka I don't understand your 2nd comment exactly. Maybe I did it wrong. Should I add this line: ```root.after(30000, incTemperature, self.EntryTemperatureInc.get(), self.EntryEndTemperature.get())``` in def incTemperature which is **not** in my tkinter class - if yes - I get an error. Or in my tkinter class? If in tkinter class, I did and I have no solution yet.

Comment: Check my edit, you call incTemperature method initially from your "Tkinter" class and then it calls itself from the inside.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this does not work for me. The function incTemperature is in the module Serialport, so it shows me errors for self.EntryTemperatureInc.get() and self.EntryEndTemperature.get() with "undefined variable self". If I delete the self keyword the same error for EntryTemperatureInc.

Comment: Create function `get_temperatures` where you get and return those temperatures from within other module. Or other way around, move this incTemperature there and crucial parts in that serialport module. Btw, use correct Python naming, modules and functions are lowercase.